# How to delete/update records inside trigger based on the updated/deleted row?

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, sql-delete

I have a table with the following format

id | name | supervisor_id

I made a "BEFORE INSERT" trigger that checks if the supervisor_id exists in the id column and if not, then assign a null value to the supervisor_id.

I am trying to write two more triggers. One that checks if the supervisor_id exists in the id column before each update of the supervisor_id, and one that sets the supervisor_id to NULL for each employee if his supervisor is deleted.

This is my code, of course it's not working, help please.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EAP_users_TRG3
AFTER DELETE
  ON EAP_users
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  d NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT id INTO d FROM EAP_users WHERE id = :OLD.id;
  UPDATE EAP_users SET supervisor = NULL WHERE supervisor = d;
END;
/
```

This is the "working" trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EAP_users_TRG1
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON EAP_users
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  supervisor EAP_users.supervisor%TYPE;
  CURSOR supervisor_CUR IS SELECT idFROM EAP_users;
  b BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  IF ( :NEW.supervisor IS NOT NULL ) THEN
    FOR s IN supervisor_CUR LOOP
      IF ( :NEW.supervisor = s.id ) THEN
        b := TRUE;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF (b = FALSE) THEN
      :NEW.supervisor := NULL;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: "not working" **HOW**?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, could you edit your question to show the code of the "working" trigger ? This might help us to pinpoint your issue more clearly maybe.

Comment: [`ORA-04091`](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm) ?

Comment: You could have the system perform this check automatically by defining the supervisor_id field as a foreign key to the id field. Your design is not how I would model the table, but adding a FK gives you what you want without changing the structure of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition of your problem, you are trying to enforce *referential integrity* of your data. In that case, a trigger is probably **not** the right tool. To quote [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#sthref3191):

> You can use both triggers and integrity constraints to define and enforce any type of integrity rule. However, Oracle strongly recommends that you use triggers to constrain data input only in the following situations:
>
> - [...]
> - When a required referential integrity rule cannot be enforced using the following integrity constraints:
>
>   - NOT NULL, UNIQUE
>   - PRIMARY KEY
>   - **FOREIGN KEY**
>   - CHECK
>   - DELETE CASCADE
>   - **DELETE SET NULL**

In that particular case you *should* use `FOREIGN KEY` constraint using the `DELETE SET NULL` modifier. Assuming you have an index on `id`, all you need is:

```
ALTER TABLE EAP_users
  ADD CONSTRAINT EAP_users_supervisor_cst
      FOREIGN KEY (supervisor_id)
      REFERENCES EAP_users(id)
      ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

This simple referential integrity constraint will perform probably better the same things as your 3 triggers -- namely:

- prevent insert/update with a non existing (non-NULL) `supervisor_id`
- set all `supervisor_id` to NULL when you delete the supervisor

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f8fb/1 for a live example.

Comment: Definitely agree: Constraints are declarative, visible (become part of the schema) and not prone to coding/logic errors. Triggers are the opposite in all senses and therefore a bad design choice.